# RewriteRule to PHP PATH_INFO and hiding destination php script

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, pathinfo

I am trying to use Apache mod_rewrite to achieve the following:

In the document root, I have these files (for example):

```
.htaccess
index.php
dlscript.php
```

I want `/downloads/this_is_path_info` to be rewritten to `/dlscript.php/this_is_path_info`, so:

```
RewriteRule ^downloads$ downloads/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^downloads/(.*) dlscript.php/$1 [NE,L]
```

The above does that.

Yet, I want the request to file `/dlscript.php` returns a HTTP 404 code, so I try:

```
RewriteRule ^dlscript.php - [R=404,L]
```

But this also 404 `/downloads/`. I've tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /dlscript.php`, but it seems mod_rewrite replaces %{REQUEST_URI} with the rewritten one.

How could I block direct access to `dlscript.php` yet enabling the other rewrites?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Jon Lin I've come up with this idea:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dlscript.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /dlscript.php
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

And this worked. The first rule is to prevent problem in ErrorDocument.

But I wonder if this should be considered as a "hack"? Any other appropriate method? Let's say I also want to `ErrorDocument /error.php` and makes `/error.php` returns 404, other methods instead of handling it inside the php script itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /dlscript.php
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L]
```

Matching against `%{THE_REQUEST}` ensures that you aren't matching against an internally rewritten URI.

Comment: This inspire me to this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dlscript.php` `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|TRACE)\ /dlscript.php` `RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]` And this worked. But I wonder if this should be considered as a "hack"? (P.S. the extra rule is to prevent problem in ErrorDocument)